# Redux DevTools clear actions history browser plugin

Tags: redux, ngrx, redux-devtools

With the Redux DevTools browser plugin, in the "Actions" pane on the left, I am only interested in the new actions that happen after I do something.  All of the previous actions are verbose clutter.  Is there a way I can clear the Actions?

Comment: Press the "commit" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you use the `commit` button within the DevTools

> Remove all actions from the log, and make the current state your initial state

[image]